# Prove that $e^{-x}I(x \geq 0)$ is a measurable function in the Lebesgue measure space given by $(R, \mathcal{B}, \lambda)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

How would I prove this? I want to use the definition that a function $X: \Omega \rightarrow R$ ($X: R \rightarrow R$ in this case) is measurable if for $x \in R$, the set $[\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) \leq x]$ is measurable (belongs in $\mathcal{B}$). Would this be the right method, and if so, how do I move forward with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** You know that $I(x \geq 0)$ is measurable. Then, all you have to do is prove that $e^{-x}$ is measurable, since the product of measurable functions is measurable too.

*Simpler.* Notice that since $f:= x \mapsto e^{-x}$ is a continuous function, we have $f^{-1}((-\infty, x])$ is closed and belongs to $\mathcal{B}$.

*Proof using that it is a limit of simple functions.*
For that, you can write $e^{-x}$ as an increasing limit of simple functions, and use that the limit of measurable functions is measurable. Try to make the usual construction of partioning into dyadic intervals; this approach is similar to the construction of integral of a positive measurable function with respect to a measure done in Bartle's book.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. Could you explain how this construction would work? I have not learned about a diadic interval.

Comment: Consider $[0, 1]$ for example. At step $n$ you divide it into $2^n$ intervals of length $2^{-n}$. Dyadic here means that we are dividing into powers of two. This is sometimes better than dividing into intervals of length $1/n$ because with dyadic intervals the partitions are nested. Thus, if $I_n^{j}$ with $j=1, \ldots, 2^n$ are the intervals at stage $n$, you can consider $f_n = \min\{e^{-x}; x \in I_n^{j}\}$ on interval $I_n^{j}$. This is approximating $e^{-x}$ from below on the interval $[0, 1]$.

Comment: Actually, using your definition of measurable it is simpler than what I described.